# Custom domain redirecting to index.html in firebase

Tags: caching, browser, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

So I just linked my custom domain with firebase and it shows connected:
[image of connected status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJyDj.png)
which is great. But now when I search [website without /index.html](https://kandarpgautam.tk), it redirects me to [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eynZz.png). I want to see [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEfzY.png) which is accessible only when I append [website domain with /index.html](https://kandarpgautam.tk/index.html). I am new to firebase. How can I make my domain access index.html page without specifically mentioning /index.html?

**EDIT:** I just noticed that it's working fine on the mobile devices and in the incognito tab on PC. It must be something with my chrome browser I am logged in with. which is weird :/ should I change the title? Cause I think fault could be related to browser. but help me if you can.

Comment: https://kandarpgautam.tk/index.html shows the same page, therefore it is rather unclear what you're asking.... besides, the question doesn't offer the least details about the hosting configuration.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I just noticed it does work fine on phone and in incognito mode of my browser but not in the normal browser tab. :/ So the issue is not what I thought it was. Is it because of browser cache or something?

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks. I just cleared the cache of the browser. I don't know why it was like that but now it's fixed. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the real issue wasn't the configuration but the browser cache. if you are facing similar issues then try clearing the browser cache or try browsing the website on a different device. Spent literally 1-2 hrs on such a silly problem. Either way, thank you.